# Copy Datagridview to clipboard in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, datagridview, copy-paste

I would like to copy Datagridview selected rows to clipboard and paste them in notepad or Microsoft Word. What is the best method to achieve this?

Thank you..

Comment: I would like to copy the rows using CTRL C.

Answer (score 4):

I use a Copy menu item. If you want to use Ctrl+C, then you'll have to implement keyboard events. Here is my code:

```
private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       foreach (Control myControl in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls)
       {
             if (myControl is DataGridView))
             {
                    DataGridView tempdgv = (DataGridView)myControl;
                    DataObject dataObj = tempdgv.GetClipboardContent();
                    try
                    {
                        Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj, true);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                         // Do Something
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (selectAllToolStripMenuItem.Checked)
                        {
                            selectAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                        }

                    }
                }
     }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with this code?

    private DataObject OnCopySelectedRowsToClipboard()
    {
            this.MyDataGridView.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableWithoutHeaderText;


                    // Add the selection to the clipboard.
                    Clipboard.SetDataObject(
                        this.MyDataGridView.GetClipboardContent());

                return new DataObject(Clipboard.GetText());

   }

Comment: Nothing except I'm not sure why you are doing return new DataObject(Clipboard.GetText()); but it should have no effect that I can see

Answer (score 1):

See [How to: Enable Users to Copy Multiple Cells to the Clipboard from the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dec5efh1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This will copy the currently selected cells in the DataGridView called `myDataGridView` data to the clipboard.

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject(myDataGridView.GetClipboardContent())
```